# How to use Gtk3 GtkTreeRowReference in Python

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gtk3, pygobject

I'm trying to call Gtk3's `GtkTreeRowReference()` function without any success. I'm trying to delete multiple records from a `ListStore` using the associated TreeView's selection set to MULTIPLE mode. I want to save a `TreeRowReference` for each `ListStore` item pointed to in the selection and use those to delete the `ListStore` items because those paths are supposed to get updated as ListStore items reached earlier in the selection get deleted. I've found many references to using `TreeRowReferences` in PyGtk 2 and the tutorial for PyGObject refers to their use but gives no actual example. I've tried many ways to invoke `GtkTreeRowReference()` without success.  For example:

```
hit_rows = []
for row in range(len(self.selection.get_selected_rows()):
    hit = self.selection.get_selected_rows()[row]
    hit_row = Gtk.TreeRowReference(liststore, hit)
    hit_rows.append(hit_row)
```

produces this fatal error message: `"TypeError: function takes at most 0 arguments (2 given)"` when my program hits the `Gtk.TreeRowReference` line. The rows in the selection already contain a reference to the `ListStore`, so tried again with only the selection row as an argument, but that just got the complaint that the function still insists on 0 arguments and I had tried to pass it 1 argument.

I also tried things like this:

```
hit_rows = []
for row in range(len(self.selection.get_selected_rows())):
    hit = self.selection.get_selected_rows()[row]
    hit_row = hit.GtkTreeRowReference()
    hit_rows.append(hit_row)
```

These efforts provoked Python to complain about an `"AttributeError: 'ListStore' object has no attribute 'GtkTreeRowReference'."` Varying the invocation to `TreeRowReference`,  `Gtk_TreeRowReference` and several other variations produced the same error message.

Can anyone spare me a clue about how to use `Gtk.TreeRowReference` in PyGObject/Gtk3? As a relatively new and inexperienced Python programmer who's also new to Gtk, no doubt I've overlooked something breathtakingly obvious, but I'm stumped even after much internet searching.

Comment: See the doc for get_selected_rows().  Looks like you just need to use the ctor on each path in the returned information.

Comment: I can get the Gtk.TreePath values returned by get_selected_rows(). What I'd like to be able to do is go on to do what the docs suggest be done if one wants to change the contents of the TreeModel using those return values, namely save them as TreeRowReferences so that they will remain valid as items get deleted or moved.

Comment: TreeRowReference constructor takes a path...doesn't that do what you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of just calling `Gtk.TreeRowReference` now (PyGObject + GTK+ 3) you have to use `Gtk.TreeRowReference.new`. For instance, you could use:

```
selection = treeview.get_selection()
model, paths = selection.get_selected_rows()
refs = []
for path in paths:
    refs.append(Gtk.TreeRowReference.new(model, path))
```

That is, `treeview` has been defined before.  Then, you can double check it later with something like:

```
for ref in refs:
    path = ref.get_path()
    iter = model.get_iter(path)
    value = model.get(iter, 0)[0]
    print '(%s, %s)' % (path, value)
```

In the last part, I assume you want to get the value of the first column in the model.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer! I just noticed it recently, hence the delay in acknowledging it.